# Kia Rio doesn't start sometimes

Tags: starting, kia, ignition-key, rio

is it common for 2012 Kia Rio to intermittently start. when my problem started the key wouldn't go all the way into the ignition. I would have to jiggle it to get it all the way in or it wouldn't turn. After a week the key would go in every time and turn, I could hear a click but car wouldn't start. After a few tries it would start easily. Last night it took four hours for the car to start. Radio works fine every time. I'm wondering if this could be an ignition problem or a starter problem.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Just to clarify: currently, when you turn the key to *ON*, the radio/electronics turn on, but then when you turn the key further to the *START* position, you just hear a click?

Comment: Sounds like an ignition switch problem. Replace the ignition switch.

Answer (score 1):

it's probably the ignition switch.  However, it's possible that your starter is going bad and the first incident with the key was a coincidence.  A mechanic could determine which is the issue in five minutes with a volt meter.  You could yourself as well with a helper (to turn the key) if you are good with tools.  Hook one end of the volt meter to ground and the other to the solenoid wire on the starter.  When the key is in crank the wire is supposed to have 12v on it.  If it does not, it's 99% the ignition switch.  If it does, it was the starter.